# istio-pilot on minikube is always in pending state

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm, istio

istio-pilot pod on minikube kubernetes cluster is always in Pending state. Increased CPU=4 and memory=8GB. Still the status of istio-pilot pod is Pending.

Is specific change required to run istio on minikube other than the ones mentioned in documentation?

Comment: Please provide the output of `kubectl describe pod <istio-pilot's pod name>`

Comment: Can you provide more background on what kind of system you are running minikube too?

Comment: Did you use any manual to install istio? Could you provide a link?

Answer (score 6):

Resolved the issue . Im running minikube with Virtual box and running minikube with higher memory and CPU does not reflect until minikube is deleted and started with new parameters. Without this it was resulting in Insufficient memory.

Answer (score 2):

I saw `istio-pilot` in 1.1 rc3 consume a lot of CPU and was in `Pending` state due to the following message in `kubectl describe <istio-pilot pod name> -n=istio-system`:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  1m (x25 over 3m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available:
1 Insufficient cpu, 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

I was able to reduce it by doing `--set pilot.resources.requests.cpu=30m` when installing istio using helm.

https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/1.1.0-rc.3/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/pilot/values.yaml#L16