# Cannot install Istio in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have created a Kubernetes cluster in my PC (master + 2 nodes). Version is `1.13.2`. Afterwards, I installed Istio using the guidelines in https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/download-release and 
https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start (version is `1.0.5`).

After checking the status of the pods, I see that the `istio-pilot` pod is always in status `Pending`, while some other pods fail as well. After several iterations, the result is always the same.

[image]

Initially the Master node has 2 cores/4 GB RAM and I increased it to 5 cores / 6 GB RAM, but the result is still the same. There are also 2 Worker nodes with 2 cores / 2 GB RAM each.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you sure that the cluster is fully operational? Are all the system pods running correctly in `kube-system` namespace?

Comment: Can you please share the full output from 'kubectl get pod/<servicegraph-...>  -n <your-istio-namespace> -o yaml'. What installation option exactly you have picked up from Istio`s website ?

Comment: it's old issue, try `kubectl logs <pilot-pod-name> -n istio-system`, seen this behaviour due to insufficient memory. Similar question but for minikube: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519668/istio-pilot-on-minikube-is-always-in-pending-state?rq=1

Comment: Look at `kubectl describe <failing pod>`. This should include information on why the pods are failing. Since the failures are cluster-wide, it is likely insufficient resources, like @murarisumit suggests.

Answer (score 0):

most likely the pods that are failing could be stateful pods. can you check those manifests and update the volume to emptyDir